# Cannot Bind Model Object to TextBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to enter a 'UserId' in the texbox and when I click on 'Find User' button, I need to get 'UserName' and 'Role' from Database based on the UserId and display them in the texboxes so that if Username and Role have to be edited they will be edited and Updated to Database.

But, when I enter UserId, the UserId value is available in the Model, and I am able to query teh database and get the results and assign them to the Model's UserName and Role (Model.UserName and Model.Role), but I am unable bind them to HTML.TextBoxFor.

I have a model like below

```
public class EditUserInfoModel
    {

        [Display(Name = "User ID")]
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "User Name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Role")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

..and Controller like below

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditUserInfo(EditUserInfoModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DMSCON"].ConnectionString;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection dbCon = new SqlConnection(con);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "select user_name,user_role from user_info where
        user_id=@userid";
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userid", model.UserId));
        cmd.Connection = dbCon;
        dbCon.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        dap.Fill(dt);
        EditUserInfoModel myModel = new EditUserInfoModel();
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            myModel.UserName = row["user_name"].ToString();
            myModel.Role = row["user_role"].ToString();
            //model.isBlocked =  (bool)row[""];
            //model.isExpired = (bool)row[""];
            // model.UserId = "somevalue";
        }

        return View("EditUserInfo", myModel);
    }
    return View();
}
```

and the View like below

```
@model WebDMS.Models.EditUserInfoModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EditUserInfo";
    //Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPage1.cshtml";
}
<h2>
    EditUserInfo</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>EditUserInfoModel</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Role)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Role)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Role)
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Find User" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do little modification in your controller action method and view model.

**Model**

```
public class EditUserInfoModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User ID")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Role")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditUserInfo(EditUserInfoModel model)
{
    string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DMSCON"].ConnectionString;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection dbCon = new SqlConnection(con);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "select user_name,user_role from user_info where
    user_id=@userid";
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userid", model.UserId));
    cmd.Connection = dbCon;
    dbCon.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    dap.Fill(dt);
    EditUserInfoModel myModel = new EditUserInfoModel();
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        myModel.UserName = row["user_name"].ToString();
        myModel.Role = row["user_role"].ToString();
    }

    //return View("EditUserInfo", myModel);    //try removing this line
     return View(myModel);      
}
```

If you use `dataannotations` then you do not need to check `ModelState.IsValid` in your action method. Your `@ValidationMessage` on your form fields inside your view will have more meaning then and will work as expected

you do not need to explicitly call the view name. Let the MVC-3 handles that. Instead try it as mentioned in this response.

these are not i would say managed and structured approach though. Always `Close()` and `Dispose()` your Db connections by putting them in `using()` block or `try-catch-finally` block. Make a layered structure so you can separate your database interaction from your controller actions. Hope it helps.